# Pulling email address from spreadsheet adds double brackets and causes MemberKey error

Tags: double, brackets

I have the following code which works:

```
function addGroupMember() {
  var userEmail = 'name@email.com';
  var groupEmail = 'group@email.com';
  var member = {
    email: userEmail,
    role: 'MEMBER'
  }
  member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
  Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);
}
```

The following code which grabs the name and group info from a spreadsheet fails with "Missing required field: memberKey"

```
function addGroupMember() {
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
 var userEmail = values.getRange(17, 5).getDisplayValues();
 var groupEmail = values.getRange(1, 1).getDisplayValues();
 var member = {
   email: userEmail,
    role: 'MEMBER'
 }
  Logger.log(member)
member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);
}
```

the "Logger.log(member)" returns:
[16-06-16 17:04:11:024 EDT] {role=MEMBER, email=[[name@email.com]]}

Please

Where are the double brackets coming from and how do I rid myself of them?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I know you were all working so hard but it was solved by our intern. (yes, we should all feel bad, I personally am going to go home and deny myself Ice Cream). The issue was in the use of getvalues instead of getvalue.

So there.